# mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages still finds and installs global packages in new environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am using virtualenvwrapper to create/manage my virtual environments. Upon running pip freeze on my environments, I was surprised to find that several tens of Python modules and packages (installed before I knew about virtualenv/wrapper), are being installed in my new environment.

This is NOT the expected behaviour; I want to have a clean environment, where only the packages I have installed in that environment, are available.

The command I'm using is:

`mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages mynewenv`

When I run `pip freeze` in that new environment, I get the following long list (I was expecting nothing to be installed in the new environment):

```
apturl (0.5.2)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
bleach (1.5.0)
blinker (1.3)
Brlapi (0.6.4)
chardet (2.3.0)
checkbox-support (0.22)
command-not-found (0.3)
coverage (3.7.1)
cryptography (1.2.3)
Cython (0.25.2)
decorator (4.0.10)
defer (1.0.6)
Django (1.10.5)
djangorestframework (3.5.3)
entrypoints (0.2.2)
enum34 (1.1.6)
feedparser (5.1.3)
guacamole (0.9.2)
html5lib (0.999)
httplib2 (0.9.1)
idna (2.0)
ipykernel (4.5.2)
ipython (5.1.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
ipywidgets (5.2.2)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (4.4.0)
jupyter-console (5.0.0)
jupyter-core (4.2.1)
language-selector (0.1)
louis (2.6.4)
lxml (3.5.0)
lz4 (0.8.2)
Mako (1.0.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
mistune (0.7.3)
mockextras (1.0.2)
nbconvert (5.0.0)
nbformat (4.2.0)
notebook (4.3.1)
numpy (1.11.3)
oauthlib (1.0.3)
onboard (1.2.0)
padme (1.1.1)
pandas (0.19.2)
pandocfilters (1.4.1)
pbr (1.10.0)
pexpect (4.0.1)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
Pillow (3.1.2)
pip (9.0.1)
plainbox (0.25)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.9)
ptyprocess (0.5)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycups (1.9.73)
pycurl (7.43.0)
Pygments (2.1)
pygobject (3.20.0)
PyJWT (1.3.0)
pymongo (3.4.0)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
pysmbc (1.0.15.5)
python-apt (1.1.0b1)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
python-debian (0.1.27)
python-systemd (231)
pytz (2016.10)
pyxdg (0.25)
pyzmq (16.0.2)
qtconsole (4.2.1)
reportlab (3.3.0)
requests (2.9.1)
sessioninstaller (0.0.0)
setuptools (23.0.0)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.10.0)
stevedore (1.15.0)
system-service (0.3)
terminado (0.6)
testpath (0.3)
tornado (4.4.2)
traitlets (4.3.1)
tzlocal (1.3)
ubuntu-drivers-common (0.0.0)
ufw (0.35)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
unity-scope-calculator (0.1)
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks (0.1)
unity-scope-colourlovers (0.1)
unity-scope-devhelp (0.1)
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks (0.1)
unity-scope-gdrive (0.7)
unity-scope-manpages (0.1)
unity-scope-openclipart (0.1)
unity-scope-texdoc (0.1)
unity-scope-tomboy (0.1)
unity-scope-virtualbox (0.1)
unity-scope-yelp (0.1)
unity-scope-zotero (0.1)
urllib3 (1.13.1)
usb-creator (0.3.0)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.6)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
wheel (0.29.0)
widgetsnbextension (1.2.6)
xdiagnose (3.8.4)
xkit (0.0.0)
XlsxWriter (0.7.3)
```

**[[Miscellaneous Information]]**

```
virtualenv --version 15.1.0 
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.2 
OS: Ubuntu 16.0.4
Python: 2.7 & 3.5
which pip : /usr/local/bin/pip
which pip3: /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: virtualenv --version 15.1.0 / virtualenvwrapper==4.7.2

Comment: Does executing `lssitepackages` within the virtualenv  give the same output?

Comment: also could you paste output of  `which pip`

Comment: @HennadiiMadan: I have updated my question (Misc Info. section), with the information you requested.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Interestingly, `lssitepackages` from the new environment gives a different output: `(twb-dataforge) me@yourbox:~/Work/ITProj/twb/dataforge$ lssitepackages
easy_install.py   pip                  pkg_resources  setuptools-32.3.1.dist-info  wheel-0.29.0.dist-info
easy_install.pyc  pip-9.0.1.dist-info  setuptools     wheel`

Comment: Assuming inspecting `~/<your-virtualenvs-folder>/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/` shows the same as `lssitepackages` then I'd guess it's a problem with `pip`.  Debians have [had some issues with pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668) in the recent past, don't know if they were fixed.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli thank you. As is apparent from your output it uses the wrong pip, it should use the one from the virtualenv. Either your virtualenv is not activated or the initialization scripts are broken. Sorry for being obvious, but please doublecheck that you activating you virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the virtualenv? It's done by "sourcing" the active script:

```
source <env>/bin/activate
```

Other problems could be long path names or spaces in the path. What does `pwd` give in the you virtualenv directory?

Comment: [Reply to a deleted comment] So you ran `workon` then? What happens if you manually source the script? And I would expect wrapper to have the same problems with long paths and spaces that virtualenv does, what is your env path?

Comment: I eventually got this to work by uninstalling virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, physically removing the ~/.virtualenv folder, removing anaconda3 from my machine, and then renaming /usr/local/bin/pip to pip.old, to force me to specify pip3.